# Minimal prime ideals are made of zero-divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity which is not an integral domain. Let $P$ be any minimal prime ideal of $R$. How can I show that $P⊆Z(R)$, where $Z(R)$ denotes the set of zero-divisors of $R.$

Comment: R is not necessary reduced.

Comment: What is Zd? The center?

Comment: I'm guessing it means the set of zero divisors of $R$.

Comment: OP: Are you forgetting your own questions?